# AWS-IoT: Access denied exception when calling get-registration-code

Tags: iot, access-denied, aws-iot

I am following the steps to register a device in AWS-IoT. I am doing the steps described [by AWS to use a self-signed certificate](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iot-self-signed-certificates/). The step three of the tutorial indicates the following command:

```
aws iot get-registration-code
```

But I am getting the following exception:

> $ aws iot get-registration-code
>
> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
>   GetRegistrationCode operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:user/dalton
>   is not authorized to perform: iot:GetRegistrationCode on resource: *

It is not clear how I can assign the right permissions. At IAM Management Console, I assigned the following permissions to my user:

> AWSIoTThingsRegistration
>
> AWSIoTLogging
>
> AWSIoTConfigAccess
>
> AWSIoTRuleActions
>
> AWSIoTConfigReadOnlyAccess
>
> AWSQuickSightIoTAnalyticsAccess
>
> AWSIoTOTAUpdate
>
> AWSIoTDataAccess
>
> AWSIoTFullAccess

Still without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWSIoTFullAccess defines this policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So with that you will be able to execute the call according to the [IAM IoT policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iam-policies.html). When attaching a new policy it only take a few seconds before it goes into effect on the CLI.

You need to :

- Double check your IAM policies and ensure that the user that is using the CLI uses indeed uses the aws credentials (key and secret) that matches the IAM user that has the AWSIoTFullAccess.
- Double check the AWS account number if you're using multiple accounts.
- Run the [AWS IAM Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp#users/testuser2/AWSIoTFullAccess) and verify the output.

[image]

Comment: It is strange, but the problem disappeared after rebooting the system. Now I get the registration code. No modification in IAM system was needed.

Comment: how do you load your aws credentials ? (via credentials file, via environment props ?) Possible that your shell had stale / other credentials when you were executing the cli cmd ?

Comment: I used the `aws configure`. I am studying the AWS IoT flow, but I think the documentation leaves some lacks, topics that could be better explained...